# Need example of pushing email address with device ID to mobile Push via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

We are trying to figure out the best way to tie users in Marketing Cloud to device IDs in mobile push.
What I would like to know:
Is it possible to check in contacts if an email address exists before creating a device ID? If so, update that contactKey with the deviceID? If so does someone have an example of the API call used to check contacts and the details of the push by the SDK where we push the contact key and email address?
Also, if the email does not exist, details of how we can include the email address from the app in the call to MC to create the deviceID.

Can anyone give an example of how they deal with this between Mobile Push and MC?

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth reviewing how the [Mobile Push SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/mobile-push-sdk.htm) works with device registration. Specifically the section in the SDK doc around [Device and Contact Registration](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html). There is a method in the SDK that is invoked to set the contact key.

> If your app doesn’t set the contact key using sfmc_setContactKey:, Marketing Cloud uses the registration sent with a contact record that matches the system token included in the registration payload. If Marketing Cloud doesn’t find a match, it sets a new contact key and doesn’t send the value back to the SDK.